# Multiple references in one superscript citation

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, biber

I want to make a bibliography like this. With one citation in superscript I want to link to the list Reference 1. With the second citation to Reference 2 and so on. And in each chapter the reference numeration should begin again from 1. Thanks.

[image]

Edit: Here is a minimal working example. You have to run this code with LaTeX, then with BIBTeX, then the EA01.tex file with LaTeX, and then again the first one with LaTeX.

```
\begin{filecontents}{EA01.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{Exp Clin Endocrinol Diabetes $\bullet$ 2001 $\bullet$ 109 Suppl 2:S122-34}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\title{Integration of biochemical and physiologic effects of insulin on glucose     metabolism}
\author{Newsholme EA\\
Merton College, Oxford, United Kingdom
\and Dimitriadis G.}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Article{EA01,
author = {E. A. Newsholme and G. Dimitriadis},
title = {\href{run:EA01.pdf}{Integration of biochemical and physiologic effects of insulin on glucose metabolism}},
journal = {Experimental and Clinical Endocrinology \& Diabetes},
year = {2001},
volume = {109 Suppl 2},
pages = {S122-34},
note = {Review}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagebackref,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
I want this cite \cite{EA01} to link a list of references, as seen in the picture.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows us what you've tried so far and illustrates the problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and suggest solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this code will do what you ask in general terms via `biblatex`.  I feel that it works in a relatively streamlined fashion, although it could certainly use some code optimization to get things working consistently with existing conventions.  Among other things, if you have invalid references, they will not be noted with the standard **??** in the document... just something to watch out for.

Here, we define a new command:

```
\def\refcite#1{
  \begin{refsegment}
  \nocite{#1}
  \footnotemark[\therefsegment]
  \end{refsegment}}
```

The end result is to have `refsections` for each chapter, which isolate the numbering schemes in `biblatex`.  Then, we use `refsegments` within each section, `\nocite` the references in each segment (relating all of the citations to a single "reference"), and manually mark the superscript as a footnotemark.

As a result of this style (as requested, as far as I could tell), regular footnotes would obviously have a clash with footnote numbering.  As I think of it now, this could be alleviated by using a citation mark such as `\textsuperscript{[\therefsegment]}` to put citations in brackets, while footnotes would remain without brackets.  Stylistic preferences must prevail here.

### The result

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

### The code

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[
  refsection=chapter,
  style=authortitle,
  backend=biber,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{refbib}[Reference~\therefsegment]{\subsection*{#1}}

\def\refcite#1{\begin{refsegment}\nocite{#1}\footnotemark[\therefsegment]\end{refsegment}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
This is cited before a section.\refcite{worman,wilde,piccato}
\section{One}

This is cited in a section.\refcite{companion,ctan}

\section*{References for Chapter~\thechapter}
\bibbysegment[heading=refbib]

\chapter{Second}
\section{One}
This is the first citation.\refcite{wilde,pines}

\section{Two}
This is the second citation.\refcite{moraux}

\section*{References for Chapter~\thechapter}
\bibbysegment[heading=refbib]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to have 2 bibliographies (using `multibib`) and a way to cite all the items without referencing them (with `\nocite{*}`)...

But I wonder : how will you reference the bibliographies ? With a `[1]` ? I'ts the items...
I tried with a `\ref` but I couldn't reference the bib title.

Anyway, here is my solution, but you'll have to reference the bibtitles yourself...
Like this : "As you can see in `References 1`, bla bla bla..."

You juste have to build 2 (or more) `.bib` files, and do so :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib} % resetlabels= to begin each bibliography at 1
\newcites{ltex}{References 1}      % Create a second bibliography with References 1 as title

\begin{document}


\nociteltex{*}                        % To cite all the items without referencing them
\bibliographystyleltex{medical}
\bibliographyltex{Med_bibstyle}       % first .bib file


\nocite{*}                            % To cite all the items without referencing them
\renewcommand{\refname}{References 2} % Title of the second bibliography
\bibliographystyle{medical}
\bibliography{Med_bibstyle_2}         % Second .bib file


\end{document}
```

Which produces this :
[image: My solution]

I hope it'll help...