# Reference style for scientific research

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I want to make a bibliography with the same style for the articles referenced as in this one. I don't know what style to choose. Here is how I made the first article:

```
@Article{EA01,
author = {Newsholme, E. A. and Dimitriadis, G.},
title = {Integration of biochemical and physiologic effects of insulin on glucose metabolism},
journal = {Experimental and Clinical Endocrinology \& Diabetes},
year = {2001},
volume = {109 Suppl 2},
pages = {S122-34},
note = {Review}}
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks like the ``plain`` style in bibtex to me

Comment: @Argo - Are you sure? To mention just three differences: The `plain` style lists first names *before* last names, it doesn't abbreviate first and middle names, and it doesn't place the year between the journal name and volume number.

Comment: Granted, there are some differences. I guess I should've added "at a glance".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generated a special bibstyle, with the given recommandations...
The only thing that isn't printed is the `Notes`, like the `review` in the first example.

Apart from that, I think it'll fit to what you expect...

To generate the bibstyle, I ran the `makebst.tex` file and followed the description here : [creating your bibstyle](http://www.medicalnerds.com/latex-bibliography-management-and-styles/).

It's a step-by-step solution, for those who wants to create their own bibstyle. Maybe you'll find how to include the notes...

I provided you a [Med_bibstyle.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgqk0thlfb04at0/Med_bibstyle.zip) with all the stuff you need (via dropbox) :

- `medical.bst` file (the bibstyle file)
- `Med_bibstyle.tex` (a empty tex file to compile)
- `Med_bibstyle.bib` (the bib file with the examples entries)

I hope it'll do it ;)

Here's the output : 
[image: Output]

A lot of success though your medical studies ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a companion to my `biblatex` solution from [the OP's previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182681/47522).

This will typeset the bibliography with the style indicated.

#### Final result

[image: bibliography]

#### Code

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{newsholme,
  title={Integration of biochemical and physiologic effects of insulin on glucose metabolism},
  author={Newsholme, E. A. and Dimitriadis, G.},
  journal={Experimental and Clinical Endocrinology \& Diabetes},
  volume={109},
  number={Suppl 2},
  pages={S122--S134},
  year={2001},
  publisher={{\copyright} Johann Ambrosius Barth},
  note={Review}
}
@article{rivellese,
  title={Exogenous and endogenous postprandial lipid abnormalities in type 2 diabetic patients with optimal blood glucose control and optimal fasting triglyceride levels},
  author={Rivellese, Angela A. and De Natale, Claudia and Di Marino, Lucrezia and Patti, Lidia and Iovine, Ciro and Coppola, Silvana and Prato, Stefano Del and Riccardi, Gabriele and Annuzzi, Giovanni},
  journal={Journal of Clinical Endocrinology \& Metabolism},
  volume={89},
  number={5},
  pages={2153--2159},
  year={2004},
  month={may},
  publisher={Endocrine Society}
}
@article{chen,
  title={Differences in postprandial lipemia between patients with normal glucose tolerance and noninsulin-dependent diabetes mellitus.},
  author={Chen, Y. D. and Swami, SRILATHA and Skowronski, ROMAN and Coulston, A and Reaven, GERALD M},
  journal={The Journal of clinical endocrinology and metabolism},
  volume={76},
  number={1},
  pages={172--177},
  year={1993},
  publisher={American Public Health Association}
}
@article{stinson,
  title={The Regulation of Post-prandial Cellular Cholesterol Metabolism in Type 2 Diabetic and Non-diabetic Subjects},
  author={Stinson, JC and Owens, D and McBrinn, S and Collins, P and Johnson, A and Tomkin, GH},
  journal={Diabetic medicine},
  volume={10},
  number={5},
  pages={420--426},
  year={1993},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{strandberg,
  title={High plasma insulin is associated with lower LDL cholesterol in elderly individuals},
  author={Strandberg, Timo E and Tilvis, Reijo S and Lindberg, Otto and Valvanne, Jaakko and Sairanen, Sirpa and Ehnholm, Christian and Tuomilehto, Jaakko},
  journal={Atherosclerosis},
  volume={121},
  number={2},
  pages={267--273},
  year={1996},
  month={apr},
  day={5},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[
  refsection=chapter,
  style=authortitle,
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  firstinits=true,
  terseinits=true,
  maxnames=99,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


% Fix first initials
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
% Fix name ordering (all last-first order)
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
% Remove quote marks around title
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}
% Remove "In:" designator
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
% Remove italics on journal name
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
% Fix ordering of issue details
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \newunit%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+volume+number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
\newbibmacro*{date+volume+number}{%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield[parens]{number}}
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \setunit{\addcolon}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit}
% Remove "pp." from pages
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% Make style
\usepackage{amssymb} % For \blacksquare
\def\mathllap{\mathpalette\mathllapinternal}
\def\mathllapinternal#1#2{%
\llap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}
  % Make a new definition of bibliography environment
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang
     \itemindent-\leftmargin
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
     \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\hskip \bibhang \relax \ensuremath{\mathllap{\blacksquare\;\;}}\sffamily}

\defbibheading{refbib}[Reference~\therefsegment]{\subsection*{#1}}

\def\refcite#1{\begin{refsegment}\nocite{#1}\footnotemark[\therefsegment]\end{refsegment}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{One}
These are medical articles.\refcite{newsholme,rivellese,chen,stinson,strandberg}

\section*{References for Chapter~\thechapter}
\bibbysegment[heading=refbib]

\end{document}
```